# Fetch API post never falling into .then

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Here is my code which works to post data but the ".then" portion isn't triggered. How can I trigger the ".then"? The only time it falls into the ".then" is when I submit when the form is empty.

HTML:

```
<form>
                <input name="username" class="no-top input" type="text" placeholder="username"></input>
                <input name="password" class="input" type="password" placeholder="password"></input>
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-row">
                      <div class="table-cell">
                        <button class="button" type="submit" value="Login" onclick="post.account.login()"></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="box">Forgot password?</div>
                        <div class="box">Request access</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const request = new Request('http://localhost:8000/account/access', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: header,
        redirect: 'manual'
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email_address: document.getElementsByName('email_address')[0].value,
          created_date: now()
        })
      })
  fetch(request).then((response) => {
    alert('test')
    if (response.status >= 400) throw new Error("Bad response from server")
    if (response.status == 200)
      return response.json()
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log('success')
  })
```

Comment: then will  trigger automatically once ur requested url back with the response, u need to trigger manually

Comment: add a `.catch(e => console.log(e))` to the end of the chain - then you'll see the error (also check web developer tools console and network tabs) - my guess is, it's a CORS issue

Comment: sorry , its u no need to trigger manually .then

Comment: I'm not sure about you, but I personally, think I'm running into this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244910

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  var myRequest = new Request('demo.php', {method: 'POST', body: '{"foo":"bar"}'});

  fetch(myRequest)
.then(function(response) {
    if(response.status == 200) //return response.json();
    console.log(response);
    else console.log('Something went wrong on api server!');
})
 .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: It fell into it but stopped randomly falling into the .then

Answer (score 0):

If you add a .catch to the .then chain like so

```
const request = new Request('http://localhost:8000/account/access', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: header,
    redirect: 'manual'
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email_address: document.getElementsByName('email_address')[0].value,
        created_date: now()
    })
})
fetch(request).then((response) => {
    alert('test')
    if (response.status >= 400) throw new Error("Bad response from server")
    if (response.status == 200)
        return response.json()
}).then((response) => {
    console.log('success')
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

You will see what the error is

Also, look in your browsers developer tools console - I'll bet you see some error regarding CORS

Comment: It is wierd. I am posting to the database and I am not getting a cors error. But the damn thing is not falling into the '.then'

Comment: is it "falling" into the .catch - i.e. is anything logged to the console